# Measure given by $\nu(E)=\int_E gd\mu$. Want to prove $\int_\Omega fd\nu=\int_\Omega fgd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

> Define a measure $\nu$ given by $\nu(E)=\int_E gd\mu$ for all $E\subseteq\Omega$ measurable and for some measurable non-negative $g$. Prove $\int_\Omega fd\nu=\int_\Omega fgd\mu$.

First step I proved this for simple functions, which was pretty straight-forward. Also, proving $\int_\Omega fgd\mu\geq\int_\Omega fd\nu$ for any measurable non-negative $f$ was easy too. It's the other inequality I'm having trouble with.

Following definition, $\int_\Omega fgd\mu=\operatorname{Sup}\{\int_\Omega hd\nu:0\leq h\leq fg, \text{h simple}\}$. Now, if I could say that $fg\geq h$ implies $f\geq \frac{h}{g}$ then solving it would be easy, but I can because it can be undefined. So I'm stuck. Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: How did you prove the first inequality?

Comment: Once you prove it for simple $f$,monotone convergence implies the result for all non-negative measurable $f$. Finally, by considering positive/negative/real/imaginary parts, you can deduce it for all $f\in L^1(\nu)$.

Comment: $h\leq f$ implies $hg\leq fg$ and therefore $\int fgd\mu\geq \int hgd\mu=\int hd\nu$ for every simpe $h\leq f$

Comment: @peek-a-boo If f is measurable and non-negative, I can necessarily find a monotone sequence of simple functions $\{h_n\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ s.t $h_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise?

Comment: yes, that's usually a standard theorem proven in any book

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once  the statement is proven for indicator functions and thus,  for nonnegative simple functions, the results follows for all nonnegative measurable functions through the monotone convergence theorem. Indeed, for $f\geq0$ define the sequence of simple functions
$$ s_n=\sum^{n2^n-1}_{j=0} 2^{-n}j\mathbb{1}_{2^{-n}j\leq f<(j+1)2^{-n}} + n\mathbb{1}_{\{n\leq f\}}$$

It is not difficult to check that $0\leq s_n\leq s_{n+1}$ and that $\lim_ns_n=f$ pointwise (I leave the details to the OP). Another way to define $s_n$ is by setting
$$s_n(x) =\max(n,2^{-n}\lfloor 2^n f(x)\rfloor)$$
where $y\mapsto \lfloor y\rfloor$ is the *integer part* function.

The result follows then by monotone convergence theorem:
$$\int f\,d\nu=\lim_n\int s_n\,d\nu=\lim_n\int s_n g\,d\mu=\int fg\,d\mu$$

By linearity, the result extends to any real measurable function for which $\int|f|\,d\nu=\int|f|g\,d\mu<\infty$.